Some definition of a compact space requires it to be Hausdorff
I am reading https://lucris.lub.lu.se/ws/portalfiles/portal/124277769/HormanderLinearFunctionalAnalysis.pdf by Hörmander for my Functional Analysis class in which he defined a compact space to be a Hausdorff space such that every open cover could be reduced to a finite subcover (page 16). The definition I saw before only requires the finite subcover property.
I am not sure why Hörmander requires the space to be Hausdorff. Is it because a Hausdorff space is a nice one (in analysis and topology) and we very often limit our studies to Hausdorff spaces in these fields?
Thank you.

I'm not going to speculate on this specific text, but I'll confirm that the generally accepted definition of compact set in topology does not require the space to be Hausdorff.

I think so yes. When doing analysis, the least you can ask for is for a space to be Hausdorff. So non Hausdorff spaces are kind of "useless" for analysis - imagine a compact set not being closed...

@MartianInvader Gotcha. Yes in the two topology textbooks I've read, they didn't require the space to be Hausdorff. This is a functional analysis text, maybe that is the reason...

Some authors (especially, but not exclusively, people in algebraic geometry) use the term "quasi-compact" to mean "every open cover has a finite subcover" and "compact" to mean "quasi-compact and Hausdorff".  Perhaps your book is following this kind of terminological choice.  At least one standard reference for general topology (Engelking's book) also makes this choice.
The reasons for this kind of terminology are largely historical, I think, but are also related to the fact that one of the most important topologies considered in algebraic geometry is rarely Hausdorff, which causes spaces that they call "quasi-compact" to behave differently than you might expect if your experience with compactness comes mostly from Hausdorff spaces.  There's a detailed discussion of this terminology here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16971/compact-and-quasi-compact.

Thank you! Then perhaps the author of the lecture notes made this choice to emphasize that the spaces we're concerned with are Hausdorff (he didn't define quasi-compact).
